# Telnet login prompt very slow on Static IP only, possible rDNS issue?

Tags: centos, telnet

I've switched my CentOS machine from DHCP to static routing, using telnet to connect to it has gone from practically instantaneous, to taking around 30 seconds for the initial login prompt to display.

[Apparently,](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=35568) this has something to do with the server doing a reverse DNS lookup to figure out who is connecting to the box, which relies on the hosts file.

Should I add something to /etc/hosts to speed up the process? My file is extremely limited right now, this is pretty much a fresh install.

```
[root@Azaz07]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
::1     localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

Telnet0 done locally responds right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My telnet rant

In general i'd advise you to not use `telnet`, but to use `ssh` instead. Telnet is a security liability that no one should be using in this day and age. See this article for a demonstration of how someone can easily sniff telnet packets as they traverse the network using wireshark, and gain access to your credentials. Th e article is titled: [Sniffing Telnet Using Wireshark](http://blog.johnmuellerbooks.com/2011/06/07/sniffing-telnet-using-wireshark.aspx). Here's a screenshot of a login attempt using telnet:

[image: ss of wireshark sniffing telnet]

#### Fixing your issue

However, if you have to absolutely use `telnet` then I'd start by diagnosing the `telnet` command you're using with the tool, `strace`.

#### Example

To demonstrate the issue you're ultimately experiencing, I modified my `/etc/resolv.conf` file so that there was a bogus DNS server in the mix. This would cause the slowness that the OP was ultimately experiencing.

```
# /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain mydom.net.
search mydom.net.
nameserver 1.2.3.4
nameserver 192.168.1.101
```

I then ran `telnet` like so:

```
$ strace -T telnet skinner
```

This section of the output shows what's taking so long:

```
...
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3 <0.000021>
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("1.2.3.4")}, 16) = 0 <0.000023>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000012>
sendto(3, "\275N\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\7grinchy\5bubba\3net\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35 <0.000073>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000012>
sendto(3, "\373\262\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\7grinchy\5bubba\3net\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35 <0.000027>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4999)  = 0 (Timeout) <5.004038>
...
```

The above `poll` that experienced the "Timeout" was our DNS query to server 1.2.3.4 on port 53. We can see when we use the `-T` switch that, this one function call took ~5 seconds until it timed out.

We can also confirm the length of time using the `time` command like so:

```
$ time telnet skinner
Trying 192.168.1.3...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.3: Connection refused

real    0m10.030s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

#### Using a correct DNS server

Putting in a correct DNS server into `/etc/resolv.conf`, and `telnet` is now much more performant.

```
$ strace -T telnet skinner
...
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.101")}, 16) = 0 <0.000018>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000010>
sendto(3, "D\363\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\7grinchy\5mydom\3net\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35 <0.000054>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}]) <0.000009>
sendto(3, "s\342\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\7grinchy\5mydom\3net\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 35 <0.000021>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4999)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}]) <0.005300>
ioctl(3, FIONREAD, [84])                = 0 <0.000024>
recvfrom(3, "D\363\205\200\0\1\0\1\0\1\0\1\7grinchy\5mydom\3net\0\0"..., 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.101")}, [16]) = 84 <0.000016>
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4994)  = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}]) <0.003688>
...
```

Timing it using `time` also shows the same:

```
$ time telnet skinner
Trying 192.168.1.3...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.3: Connection refused

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Comment: yeah, I would if I could. We're developing software for a testing lab that uses telnet internally.

Answer (score 0):

I was using 4.2.2.1 and 4.2.2.2 for statically assigned DNS servers -- I switched these to 192.168.0.1 for the router and it resolved the issue.

Comment: It was probably trying to connect to those DNS servers and timing out.